# Thread context switch in one process & two processes

Tags: multithreading, process, context-switch

Is it faster to context-switch between two threads within the same process THAN to context switch between two threads within 2 different processes?

Comment: Are the threads in User space or Kernel space?

Comment: User space (5 more chars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - the new process context has to be loaded, memory-management registers etc.